# Javascript regex to match word with slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove 2 char words and using this regex:

```
/\b[\w\/]{2}\b/
```

given a string like: `aa bb b/`

http://regex101.com/r/dK6qF7/2

Can anyone explain why 'b/' doesn't get matched and removed?

Thanks

Comment: If you remove your word boundary `\b` it will do what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Because `/` is not considered to be a "word character" in regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` followed by the end of the string does not form a word boundary, so the last `\b` is not satisfied.  If your engine can use lookbehinds, you can use:

```
(?<=[^\w\/]|^)[\w\/]{2}(?=[^\w\/]|$)
```

Comment: unfortunately Javascript doesn't have regex lookbehinds so need to play with this to see if I can make it work in JS

Comment: @vshale You can do something like `(?:^|[^\w\/])([\w\/]{2})(?=[^\w\/]|$)`.  The difference is that the pseudo-lookbehind part is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

A word boundary will match if `\w` is followed by `\W` (i.e. `[A-Za-Z0-9_]` followed by `[^A-Za-Z0-9_]`), or vice versa.

Using the regex `\bb/\b` and the input `" b/ "`, the first word boundary matches, since a space (`\W`) is followed by `b` (`\w`). But the second word boundary won't match: `/` (`\W`) is followed by a space (`\W`).